# how to update the view based on a object change in backbone and marionette?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, marionette

i have a view:

```
define(['backbone', 'hbs!tmpl/test_tmpl'],
function (Backbone, TestTmpl) {
    'use strict';
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.projects = {};
        },
        template: TestTmpl,
        templateHelpers: function () {
            return {
                projects: this.projects
            }
        },
        ui: {},
        events: {},
        onRender: function () {
            this.projects = {title: 'a'};
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

then  in the view:

```
{{#each projects}}{{this.title}}{{/each}}
```

in the `onRender()` method i update the project `this.projects = {title: 'a'};` and when that is set, i want the view data to update as well

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call

```
this.render();
```

Typically, you would use a collectionview instead of an itemview.
If you happen to need more HTML surrounding the wrapping element, use a compositeview instead.

Note that a collectionview takes a Backbone Collection when you pass it:

```
var collectionview = new CollectionView({ collection: bbCollection });
```

An itemview takes a model:

```
var itemview = new ItemView({ model: bbModel});
```

For your example, using a collectionview removes the need to create a loop within the template.
You can access the current itemview's properties by calling

```
this.model.get("property");
```

On the itemview.

In your example, it would appear to me that you rather have an array instead of an object:

```
var projects = [{ title: "X"}, { title: "Y" }];
```

You can create a Backbone collection on the fly this way:

```
var projects_collection = new Backbone.Collection(projects);
```

And pass it on to the collectionview:

```
//First create a Marionette Collectionview, then: 
var projectsCollview = new ProjectsCollview({ collection: projects_collection });
```